# xe:objectData and global variables

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm having a problem with xe:objectData and global variables. Not sure if this is a bug or working as designed.
The sample is a dumb one, I know. It's just meant to demonstrate the issue.

1. works as expected
2. throws exception. I have seen the same behaviour, when I try to use scoped variables in xe:objectData. Always a null is returned, although the variables contain values.

Anyone to shed a light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can not use bundle resources at that time because of timing of when things occur in the lifecycle. When the objectData's create object method is called, other objects may not yet be created yet. You may have to manually load the bundle and retrieve the property you need.

Comment: That makes sense. So, once again, PhaseListener (LifeCycleListener: OpenNTF --> http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xpages-request-processing-lifecycle-explorer-code...)  is your friend when dealing with issues like that :)